# Is there a way to format date to only show month and year in plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-formatting

I have trouble to output only month and year like this
`December 2018` when I made a function to pass a parameter for the date.

I made a simple function with a parameter to return date only shows month and year with below test code. I used the `month` instead of mon as described from above, but there is a gap in between e.g. `December     2019`.

```
function get_month(p_month DATE DEFAULT sysdate)
return VARCHAR2
is

v_month varchar2(50);

begin

select to_char(trunc(p_month), 'Month yyyy') into v_month from dual;

return v_month;
commit;

end;
```

Ideally, I would expect the output of the month in full name like `to_char(sysdate,'Month DDth, YYYY')` but without the day in the middle.

Comment: Try format `'fmMonth yyyy'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA):

> Oracle uses trailing blank characters and leading zeroes to fill format elements to a constant width. The width is equal to the display width of the largest element for the relevant format model ...
>
> - The character elements MONTH, MON, DAY, and DY are padded with trailing blanks to the width of the longest full month name ...

But also:

> The FM modifier suppresses the above padding in the return value of the TO_CHAR function.

So as @WernfriedDomscheit said in a comment, add the FM modifier:

```
select to_char(trunc(p_month), 'FMMonth yyyy') into v_month from dual;
```

although the `trunc()` isn't adding anything so:

```
select to_char(p_month, 'FMMonth yyyy') into v_month from dual;
```

or more simply, avoid the context switch and just assign directly:

```
v_month := to_char(p_month, 'FMMonth yyyy');
```

Answer (score 2):

the Month option in the format string seems to be generating the output with extra whitespaces, you can trim them to get the required result.

Try this:

```
select trim(to_char(sysdate,'Month'))||' '||to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')
from dual;
```